# Any ESB frameworks which provides API to host a webservice dynamically

Tags: esb

i am performing an R&D to check whether are there any open source ESB frameworks which provides the following features
1. API to host a SOAP webservice/consume a service by providing the required data. We are working on a tool to design webservices for our product and the metadata created from the tool would be input to the API. What we are looking is that the metadata generated should be hosted as a webservice instantly without restarting the ESB container.
2. API provided by the framework to define the count of a service executions performed.
3. ESB framework which supports versioning both in hosting a service and also  consuming a service.

It would be very helpful if someone can provide a direction to such ESB frameworks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talend ESB provides the functionality you described.

1. it can consume a WSDL (your metadata created from your tool) to quickly create a web service service.  It is hot deployed into a Karaf container (i.e. do not need to restart the ESB container)
2. you can use built in logging or custom logging to count executions performed.
3. it can be hooked into git or svn for versioning.

There is a free version you can download [here](https://www.talend.com/download/).

Here is a basic [tutorial](https://www.talend.com/resources/webinars/talend-open-studio-for-esb-for-dummies/) on the product which demonstrates a. ingesting a WSDL, b. hot deployment, and c. execution count (though it does not go into how to log that).

Comment: Thanks for the info @LaRoche.

Comment: I notice you are a new user to StackOverflow.  If you are satisfied with my answer please consider marking the question as answered. Thanks